# How to add labels in percentage format in histogram hist() in R?

Tags: r, histogram

I'm using the `hist()` command r-base to generate a histogram with `freq=TRUE`.
I would like the label to be shown as a percentage.

my code without label percent

```
df<-read.csv("http://wesleysc352.github.io/correl.csv", sep=",", header = TRUE)%>%
  select(correl)

hist(unlist(df), 
     breaks = seq(-1,1,0.125),
     ylim = c(0,200),
     xaxt = "n",
     freq=TRUE,
     right = TRUE,
     main = "Histograma Frequência das Correlações",#título
     xlab="Correlação encontrada nas Área_inf", ylab="Frequência",
     labels = TRUE)
     
axis(1, at = c(-1,-0.875,-0.75,-0.625,-0.50,-0.375,-0.25,-0.125,0,0.125,0.25,0.375,0.50,0.625,0.75,0.875,1))
abline(v=c(-0.5,0.5), col=c("red", "red"), lty=c(2,2), lwd=c(3, 3))
```

[image]

I tried to use this [tip](https://statisticsglobe.com/add-count-percentage-labels-on-top-of-histogram-bars-r), but I didn't have success in my code.

```
df<-read.csv("http://wesleysc352.github.io/correl.csv", sep=",", header = TRUE)%>%
  select(correl)

hist(unlist(df), 
     breaks = seq(-1,1,0.125),
     ylim = c(0,200),
     xaxt = "n",
     freq=TRUE,
     right = TRUE,
     main = "Histograma Frequência das Correlações",#título
     xlab="Correlação encontrada nas Área_inf", ylab="Frequência",
     labels = paste0(round(hist(df, plot = FALSE)$counts/length(correl)*100, 1), "%"))
     
axis(1, at = c(-1,-0.875,-0.75,-0.625,-0.50,-0.375,-0.25,-0.125,0,0.125,0.25,0.375,0.50,0.625,0.75,0.875,1))
abline(v=c(-0.5,0.5), col=c("red", "red"), lty=c(2,2), lwd=c(3, 3))
```

Comment: nah dont do that, it requires you to call `hist` twice with the same arguments and breaks, you can do it once `h <- hist(...)` as you already have and use the object returned to do the text `text(h$mids, h$counts, sprintf('%.1f%%', h$counts / sum(h$counts) * 100), pos = 3)`

Comment: are you open to tidyverse?

Comment: I tried using `ggplot`, `geom_histogram()` but couldn't get it exactly the way I did with `hist()`. case a solution with `ggplot()` will be fine.

Comment: @rawr I tested your suggestion and it worked. would it be possible to reduce the font size of the label?

Comment: the default should be `text(..., cex = 1)`, so you can use `cex = 0.8` or lower

Comment: @rawr, I managed to adjust the graph here according to the tips. I think it's only fair for you to post the answer, once you've solved the problem.